# CefSharp with Chromium Renders text to small

Tags: chromium, cefsharp

It appears that i have trouble with cefsharp and/or chromium. 
So when i enter a webside the Text font is like 1px hight.
As you see in the first picture this is how the testwebside should be displayed, but with cefsharp it looks like 2 lines like in the 2nd picture.

I searched a lot for some help but the only similar case was caused by a missing locales folder. But i still got the locales folder with alot of entrys.

[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPOmv.png)

[How it actually looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6rgb.png)

Comment: Either your missing a pak file or pak loading is disabled in your app, those are the only two cases I'm aware of that case this issue. You can usehttps://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample to test with a known working example

Comment: Hi amaitland. Thank you for your response. There was no file missing in my lokales folder. Allthought i copied the locals file from this projects locals folder to my locals folder. Nothing changed...

Comment: It's not limited to locales, there are many other pak files, you basically need them all

Comment: hey amaitland,

these other pak files are also there. there is no single pak file missing. That's what i allready found on my research but the problem is still there...

Comment: You can test with https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Comment: Also read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#need-to-knowlimitations make sure you have an app.manifest